# Problems running Thrift C# Tutorial

Tags: c#, rpc, thrift, thrift-protocol

I am new to and need to understand the nuts / bolts of the Thrift RPC framework. For this purpose I have downloaded the Calculator tutorial (consisting of a client and server).

I thought this would be the best way to understanding whats going on under the hood.

I have been able to do the following

1. Generate the thrift.dll file
2. Generate the required csharp shource files for creating a dll - calculator.thrift.dll
3. Create a project consisting of two projects for the client and server. (note the client project is a console app and the server is a class library)

I am reproducing some code for reference from the main method of the client project

```
public static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            TTransport transport = new TSocket("localhost", 9090);
            TProtocol protocol = new TBinaryProtocol(transport);
            Calculator.Client client = new Calculator.Client(protocol);

            transport.Open();
```

The system generates an error when trying to execute the above line.

The error is as follows.

No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:9090

The one obvious solution that comes to mind is the firewall. I created some firewall rules for allowing connections on port 9090. But the error persists.

Anyone experienced with socket connections and /or thrift usage who can guide me towards a resolution of this error?

Thanks a ton in advance

Romi

Answer (score 1):

This problem is resolved. I was simply forgetting to start the server. :-)